# Any way to get a CSS selector with nth-of-type pseudoclass?

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Chrome's Inspection tool copies CSS selector with nth-child - which is not supported by bs4. 
Are there any add-ons for browsers, browsers or applications to copy CSS selector with nth-of-type pseudoclass in it?

Answer (score 1):

`BeautifulSoup` has its own CSS selector parsing implementation which basically parses a CSS selector string and translates it to "find" commands: [source code](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1505).

It is though pretty straightforward to write a `find()` or `find_all()` version of the `nth-child` in general. But, I understand, that it could be inconvenient to always keep this limitation in mind and translate a selector or part of a selector to "find" language.

As an alternative, you could check out the [`parsel` package](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) which has a better CSS selector support in general:

```
In [1]: from parsel import Selector

In [2]: sel = Selector(text="""<html>
   ...:         <body>
   ...:             <h1>Hello, Parsel!</h1>
   ...:             <ul>
   ...:                 <li><a href="http://example.com">Link 1</a></li>
   ...:                 <li><a href="http://scrapy.org">Link 2</a></li>
   ...:             </ul
   ...:         </body>
   ...:         </html>""")

In [3]: sel.css('ul li:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
Out[3]: 'http://scrapy.org'
```